# High Speed Internter can fight against Ddos Attack

Tags: web, ddos, high-traffic

I have 100mbps Broadband Internet Line. So my question is high speed internet can get some advantage browsing Ddos attacked high traffic website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From wikipedia: *In computing, a denial-of-service (DoS) or distributed denial-of-service (DDoS) attack is an attempt to make a machine or network resource unavailable to its intended users.*

Since you are a client who's trying to browse the server that is under attack, my simple logic says no. And this question is not programming related, so not proper for here.